# What is the difference between service and service provider interface?

Tags: java, service

I understand that a service is an interface defining what functions are to be implemented.

I also understand that a service provider implements these functions.

However, I can't seem to understand what a service provider interface is. Would I be correct in saying it is an interface which defines a method to instantiate the service?

Answer (score 0):

Baeldung has an answer to your question in his article: [Java Service Provider Interface](https://www.baeldung.com/java-spi):

> **Service Provider Interface**
>
> An interface or abstract class that acts as a proxy or an endpoint to the service.
>
> If the service is one interface, then it is the same as a service provider interface.
>
> Service and SPI together are well-known in the Java Ecosystem as API.